# How to Compare a String with a Char

Tags: java, compare, equals

Guys how do i compare a String with a char?

heres my code :

```
private String s;
private char c;

public K(String string, char cc){
    setS(string);
    setC(cc);
}

public void setS(String string){
    this.s = string;
}

public void setC(char cc){
    this.c = cc;
}

public boolean equals(K other){
    return s.equals(c);
}

public boolean try(){
    return s.equals(c);
}
```

if i call my method `try`, it always returns me false even if i set 
both `s = "s"` and `c = 's'`.

Comment: Compare `s.charAt(0)` and `c`.

Comment: wouldnt that be a false equivalency if string had more than 1 char? How about compare s to String.valueOf(c)

Comment: You are doing something wrong here. Your `equals` should compare the current `K` object (`this`) with some other `K` object that will be passed to it (`other`). It shouldn't compare `s` to `c` as this doesn't involve the other `K` (thus breaking the `equals` contract). Also please avoid using meaningless names, like `K`, `c`, `s`, `cc` etc.

Comment: You cannot use `try` as method name, because `try` is a reserved word in Java.

Comment: @RealSkeptic thanks for tips i will think about this next time

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first thing I would say to any of my junior devs is to not use the word "try" as a method name, because try is a reserved keyword in java.

Secondly think that there are a few things which you need to consider in your  method.

If you compare things of two different types they will never be the same. 
A String can be null.
How long the string is. 
The first char.

I would write the method like :

```
public boolean isSame() {
    if (s != null && s.length() == 1 { 
        return s.charAt(0) == c;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Either use char comparison (assuming s will always be of length 1):

```
return c == s.charAt(0);
```

Or use String comparison:

```
return s.equals(new String(new char[]{c}));
```

Comment: `Character#toString` would suffice for your second example.